# Sequence, uniform continuity, uniform convergence, pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I have an excercise. First I am asked to prove something, then I am asked to find a counterexample. However I am not able to find a counterexample, can you please help me?

Assume that the functions $f_{n}: X \rightarrow Y$ converges uniformly to $f$, and that $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ is uniformly continuous. Show that the sequence $\{g\circ f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly. Find an example which shows that the conclusion does not ncessarily hold if g is only pointwise continuous.

I know that $g(y)=y^2$, is only pointwise continuous, however I am not able to find an uniformly convergens sequence $f_{n}$ where $(f_{n})^2$ is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: $f_n(x)=x+1/n$.${}$

Comment: Doesnt that converge to $x^2$ uniformly?

Comment: Not on $\Bbb R$: $\displaystyle \bigl(\,f_n(x)\,\bigr)^2 -x ^2 ={2x\over n} +{1\over n^2}$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @DavidMitra: please consider adding this as answer!